# Validating receipts Autorenewable subscriptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, store

I know I've read this somewhere, but I just cant remember... sorry ;)

So the question is, when submitting an app to the apple store for its review, the url that checks the receipt should be the sandbox one or the production one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you neet to submit it with the production URL.